# Concatenate specific pairs of columns in a dataframe based on a reference dataframe with a different index

Tags: python, pandas

My goal is to concatenate columns in a dataframe(Source), based on pairs that 
are described in a separate dataframe(Reference). The resulting dataframe should replace the column headers in the Source with the index labels in the Reference.

## The dataframe used for referencing looks like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    FIRST=['Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Charlie'],
    SECOND=['Bravo', 'Delta', 'Delta']
), ['H1', 'H2', 'H3'])

df1

      FIRST SECOND
H1    Alpha  Bravo
H2    Alpha  Delta
H3  Charlie  Delta
```

## The dataframe used as the source of data:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Alpha=['A', 'C'],
    Bravo=['A', 'C'],
    Delta=['T', 'C'],
    Charlie=['T', 'G']
), ['item-000', 'item-111'])

df2

           Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta
item-000     A     A       T     T
item-111     C     C       G     C
```

## What the resulting dataframe will look like:

```
          H1  H2  H3
item-000  AA  AT  TT
item-111  CC  CC  GC
```

---

**Question**
Is this possible with the current set up, or would it be best to change the form the data is in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution**
Using `pd.get_dummies` and `pd.DataFrame.dot`

```
df2.dot(pd.get_dummies(df1.stack()).T).sum(1, level=0)

          H1  H2  H3
item-000  AA  AT  TT
item-111  CC  CC  GC
```

---

**Explanation**

I know I want to use a dot product.  The rule with the matrix multiplication is that an `n x k` matrix multiplied by a `k x m` matrix results in an `n x m` matrix.  Looking at the final result, I see `['item-000', 'item-111']` in the index, that is my `n` in my `n x k` matrix.  I look at my preliminary dataframes, do I have one with `['item-000', 'item-111']` in either the columns or index?  I do!

```
df2

           Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta
item-000     A     A       T     T
item-111     C     C       G     C
```

and that implies my `k` is `['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta']`.  Ok, so now I must look for `k x m`.  The only other dataframe I have is `df1` and the things that look like `['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta']` are in the values... **not** the columns or index.  So I must get it there.  I decide to stack `df1` and use `pd.get_dummies`.

```
pd.get_dummies(df1.stack())

           Alpha  Bravo  Charlie  Delta
H1 FIRST       1      0        0      0
   SECOND      0      1        0      0
H2 FIRST       1      0        0      0
   SECOND      0      0        0      1
H3 FIRST       0      0        1      0
   SECOND      0      0        0      1
```

And now I have `['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta']` in my columns!  That's my `k`.  But I need it in my index.  No problem, use transpose.

```
pd.get_dummies(df1.stack()).T

           H1           H2           H3       
        FIRST SECOND FIRST SECOND FIRST SECOND
Alpha       1      0     1      0     0      0
Bravo       0      1     0      0     0      0
Charlie     0      0     0      0     1      0
Delta       0      0     0      1     0      1
```

Right On!  Now I'm ready to `dot`

```
df2.dot(pd.get_dummies(df1.stack()).T)

            H1           H2           H3       
         FIRST SECOND FIRST SECOND FIRST SECOND
item-000     A      A     A      T     T      T
item-111     C      C     C      C     G      C
```

We are almost there.  I concatenate `FIRST` and `SECOND` by using `pd.DataFrame.sum` where I specify that I want to sum across rows and grouped by the first level of the columns object.

```
df2.dot(pd.get_dummies(df1.stack()).T).sum(1, level=0)

          H1  H2  H3
item-000  AA  AT  TT
item-111  CC  CC  GC
```

---

**Setup**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    FIRST=['Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Charlie'],
    SECOND=['Bravo', 'Delta', 'Delta']
), ['H1', 'H2', 'H3'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Alpha=['A', 'C'],
    Bravo=['A', 'C'],
    Delta=['T', 'C'],
    Charlie=['T', 'G']
), ['item-000', 'item-111'])
```

Comment: Trying to understand what's going on here... and failed. Wonderful, as always.

Comment: Thank you @MaxU!  I just really liked how that all fit together.

Answer (score 0):

There will likely be better solutions, but at least this one is working:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'FIRST': pd.Series(['Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Charlie'],
                                       index=['H1', 'H2',  'H3']),
                    'SECOND': pd.Series(['Bravo', 'Delta', 'Delta'],
                                        index=['H1', 'H2', 'H3'])})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Alpha' : pd.Series(['A', 'C'], index = ['item-000', 'item-111']),
                    'Bravo' : pd.Series(['A', 'C'], index = ['item-000', 'item-111']),
                    'Delta' : pd.Series(['T', 'C'], index = ['item-000', 'item-111']),
                    'Charlie' : pd.Series(['T', 'G'], index = ['item-000', 'item-111'])})

pd.concat((df1.T.apply(lambda x: x.map(df2.loc[idx]).str.cat())
           for idx in df2.index),
          axis=1).rename_axis(pd.Series(df2.index), axis=1).T

Out[]:
          H1  H2  H3
item-000  AA  AT  TT
item-111  CC  CC  GC
```

Of course this relies on both a `for` loop in the iterator and an `apply`, so it will not be very efficient.