# How can I get combined result of a column values in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below data in a DataFrame.

```
city    age                     
mumbai  12 33 5 55
delhi   24 56 78 23 43 55 67
kal     12 43 55 78 34
 mumbai     14 56 78 99     # Have a leading space 
MUMbai  34 59               # Have Capitol letters  
kal     11
```

I want to convert it into below format :

```
city    age
mumbai  12 33 5 55 14 56 78 99 34 59
delhi   24 56 78 23 43 55 67
kal     12 43 55 78 34 11
```

How can I achieve this?

Note: 
I have edited the data, now some city name are in Capital letter and some has leading spaces. How can we apply strip() and lower() functions to it?

Answer (score 2):

- We use `groupby` with `sort=False` to ensure we present cities in the same order they first appear.
- We use `' '.join` to concatenate the strings together.
- Lastly, we `reset_index` to get the city values that have been placed in the index into the dataframe proper.

---

```
df.groupby('city', sort=False).age.apply(' '.join).reset_index()

     city                           age
0  mumbai  12 33 5 55 14 56 78 99 34 59
1   delhi          24 56 78 23 43 55 67
2     kal             12 43 55 78 34 11
```

---

**Response to Edit**

```
df.age.str.strip().groupby(
    df.city.str.strip().str.lower(),
    sort=False
).apply(' '.join).reset_index()

     city                           age
0  mumbai  12 33 5 55 14 56 78 99 34 59
1   delhi          24 56 78 23 43 55 67
2     kal             12 43 55 78 34 11
```

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 thank you for your feedback.  My expectation is that the intention of the code is simple enough that it explains itself.  If you disagree, let me know and I'll be happy to add further explanation. (-:

Comment: As evidence that do post more than code, see [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596056/2336654)

Comment: Thanks that works. Now I have edited my question. What if it has some capital letter and leading spaces? How can we use strip() and lower() methods here?

Comment: @m.j I've edited my question.  As a heads up, It's usually bad form to change the nature of the question after the fact.