# How to do keyword mapping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, word2vec

I have keyword

```
India
Japan
United States
Germany
China
```

Here's sample dataframe

```
id    Address 
1     Chome-2-8 Shibakoen, Minato, Tokyo 105-0011, Japan
2     Arcisstraße 21, 80333 München, Germany
3     Liberty Street, Manhattan, New York, United States
4     30 Shuangqing Rd, Haidian Qu, Beijing Shi, China
5     Vaishnavi Summit,80feet Road,3rd Block,Bangalore, Karnataka, India
```

My Goal Is make

```
id    Address                                                          India Japan United States  Germany China    
1     Chome-2-8 Shibakoen, Minato, Tokyo 105-0011, Japan              0     1     0              0       0                  
2     Arcisstraße 21, 80333 München, Germany                          0     0     0              1       0
3     Liberty Street, Manhattan, New York, USA                        0     0     1              0       0
4     30 Shuangqing Rd, Haidian Qu, Beijing Shi, China                0     0     0              0       1
5     Vaishnavi Summit,80feet Road,Bangalore, Karnataka, India        1     0     0              0       0
```

The basic idea is create keyword detector, I am thinking to use `str.contain` and `word2vec` but I can't get the logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of `pd.get_dummies()`:

```
countries = df.Address.str.extract('(India|Japan|United States|Germany|China)', expand = False)
dummies = pd.get_dummies(countries)
pd.concat([df,dummies],axis = 1)
```

Also, the most straightforward way is to have the countries in a list and use a for loop, say

```
countries = ['India','Japan','United States','Germany','China']
for c in countries:
    df[c] = df.Address.str.contains(c) * 1
```

but it can be slow if you have a lot of data and countries.

Comment: This has a typo and doesn't run.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [58]: df = df.join(df.Address.str.extract(r'.*,(.*)', expand=False).str.get_dummies())

In [59]: df
Out[59]:
   id                                            Address   China   Germany   India   Japan   United States
0   1  Chome-2-8 Shibakoen, Minato, Tokyo 105-0011, J...       0         0       0       1               0
1   2             Arcisstra?e 21, 80333 Munchen, Germany       0         1       0       0               0
2   3  Liberty Street, Manhattan, New York, United St...       0         0       0       0               1
3   4   30 Shuangqing Rd, Haidian Qu, Beijing Shi, China       1         0       0       0               0
4   5  Vaishnavi Summit,80feet Road,3rd Block,Bangalo...       0         0       1       0               0
```

NOTE: this method will not work if country is not at the last position in `Address` column or if country name contains `,`

Comment: I’m on my phone. I answered from top of my head. Can you please verify that my answer works?

Comment: It’s a ufunc for str.find. I can use broadcasting across addresses and keywords. If keyword is found the position is returned. Otherwise-1 is returned.  Hence >= 0

Comment: thank you. I’ll fix it in a few hours when I’m back at a computer.

Comment: @piRSquared, sorry, i'm blind. I didn't see `from numpy.core.defchararray import find` - now it works as expected :)

Comment: Not sure if you saw this one.  I was particularly proud of it (-:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596056/2336654

Answer (score 2):

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

kw = 'India|Japan|United States|Germany|China'.split('|')
a = df.Address.values.astype(str)[:, None]

df.join(
    pd.DataFrame(
        find(a, kw) >= 0,
        df.index, kw,
        dtype=int
    )
)

   id                        Address  India  Japan  United States  Germany  China
0   1  Chome-2-8 Shibakoen, Minat...      0      1              0        0      0
1   2  Arcisstraße 21, 80333 Münc...      0      0              0        1      0
2   3  Liberty Street, Manhattan,...      0      0              1        0      0
3   4  30 Shuangqing Rd, Haidian ...      0      0              0        0      1
4   5  Vaishnavi Summit,80feet Ro...      1      0              0        0      0
```