# Can't read a column after pivoting pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have table that I came from a pivot table to eliminate missing values and too short value like city name, here's my code

```
company = pd.read_sql('SELECT user_id, address FROM company' , con=db_connection)
table = pd.pivot_table(company, index=['address'],aggfunc=np.sum)
table.reset_index()
```

Then I get his

```
    address                                             user_id
3   Jl. Raya Kranggan No. 7, Ruko Kav V No. 1 Jat...    65132
4   #ALAMAT atau LOKASI\r\nKota bengkulu perhubung...   15570
5   '--!>'</script/><Svg/Onload=confirm`alamat bis...   48721
6   (Rumah Bpk.RA'IS) Jl.Puskesmas RT.004/11 No.29...   20786
```

It seems OK when I check the colums

```
table.columns
Index(['user_id', 'address'], dtype='object')
```

Then I can't call a column

```
table['address']
```

When I call that column, this is happen

```
 KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
       2392             try:
    -> 2393                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
       2394             except KeyError:

    pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5239)()

    pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5085)()

    pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20405)()

    pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20359)()

KeyError: 'address'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-eef3b78ea5fd> in <module>()
----> 1 table['address'] #.astype(str)

C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2060             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2061         else:
-> 2062             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2063 
   2064     def _getitem_column(self, key):

C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2067         # get column
   2068         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2069             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2070 
   2071         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1532         res = cache.get(item)
   1533         if res is None:
-> 1534             values = self._data.get(item)
   1535             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1536             cache[item] = res

C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3588 
   3589             if not isnull(item):
-> 3590                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3591             else:
   3592                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2393                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2394             except KeyError:
-> 2395                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2396 
   2397         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5239)()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5085)()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20405)()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20359)()

KeyError: 'address'
```

If you have other solution, it's fine as long as I can map the address to do [keyword mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601437/how-to-do-keyword-mapping-in-pandas)

Comment: what does `table[table.columns[1]]` give

Comment: `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`

Comment: Recheck `table.columns` if there are two elements then index 1 should work

Comment: `address` is an index name - not a column

Comment: Maybe you forget assign back `table = table.reset_index()`

Comment: `table.columns`  give me     `Index(['user_id'], dtype='object')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need asign output of [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) back, because `address` is index name, no column:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(company, index='address',aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()
```

Another solutions if want define columns for aggregate `sum`:

```
table = company.groupby('address', as_index=False)['user_id'].sum()
```

Or:

```
table = company.groupby('address')['user_id'].sum().reset_index()
```

And for all columns:

```
table = company.groupby('address', as_index=False).sum()
```

---

```
table = company.groupby('address').sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `pivot` is a proper choice here.

You can use this:

```
company.groupby('address').sum()
```

Comment: Do I need still reset index

Comment: @NabihIbrahimBawazir, you can use `as_index=False` parameter instead